# iTunes Match "upgraded" one of my songs with a glitchy version. Now what?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I signed up for iTunes Match. It matched most of my songs and uploaded the rest. I was playing one of my favorite songs and discovered it has a glitch at 21 seconds in. It is consistently there, even on multiple devices. Luckily I found I still had my copy in a backup, so I removed the song from the iTunes library and re-added it. Unfortunately it is one of the songs Apple "matched" so it keeps getting replaced with the glitchy version.

I guess I could try renaming the song so Apple doesn't keep replacing it, but that seems like a lot of work. What else can I do?

Comment: Unless you tell iTunes to download the file, it should keep your existing version, so I'm not sure how yours is being replaced all the time. Renaming won't help because from what I can tell, it runs some algorithm on the file contents.

Comment: @Randolph I keep all my original music on the backup drive then play it from the cloud on all my devices.

Comment: You also may want to contact iTunes support (http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/) to notify them of the glitchy song, so they can correct it in their system.

Comment: @jmlumpkin I Contacted Apple iTunes support and they have a hard time comprehending that there is a problem with one of their songs. I went to the Genius Bar today and the Genius had the same song on her iPhone and it played the same for her. Hopefully they can get it fixed now.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth did you ever get any feedback from this?

Comment: @jmlumpkin I finally got escalated to a senior tech who actually listened to the song and said they would get it replaced. Said it will take 4-6 weeks.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth glad to hear. im hoping to get ANY feedback from Apple on an explicit/clean mixup.

Comment: What song was it?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt IIRC correctly it was "Whisper of Angels" by Amici Forever. I know that was the group, but not sure which track.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding (although not precise science) so far with Match knows the song signature and uses this in conjunction with the track length to match against their database.

This would explain why some songs get replaced with explicit versions on Match while renaming one song to another (incorrect) does not trick Match into thinking it is a new song. You can test both quite easily

- the former by deleting a non explicit matched song (remembering track length) and pulling it back from iCloud
- the latter by ripping a CD without any info into Track01...02 etc and have it matched correctly.

all the above is somehow tied with Genius.

With the above assumption, to keep your proper version try padding out the length, add noise, or combine the track with the next (if it belongs to an album) and it should cause enough difference to be uploaded instead of being matched.

Comment: As a side note, always remember that iTunes Match is not a backup solution. Remember to keep copies of your library